# SQL - Inserting values of another table into multiple columns and embed them in predefined values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and want to insert the values of table 1 in table 2:

```
Table 1: tx_abc_domain_model_abc
Columns: crdate, uid, xyz

Table 2: tx_realurl_urldata
Columns: crdate, page_id, rootpage_id, original_url, speaking_url, request_variables, expire
```

... where the values of table 1 ...

```
crdate_table1
uid_table1
xyz_table1
```

... should be embedded as sub-parts in predefined values like this in table 2:

```
SET VALUES (crdate_table1, 43, 1, 'id=43&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=Abc&tx_lei_lei%5Brecord%5D=uid_table1', 'abc/xyz_table1/', '{"id":"43","tx_abc_abc[record]":"uid_table1","tx_abc_abc[action]":"show","tx_abc_abc[controller]":"Abc"}', 0);
```

So the result should e.g. look like

```
(crdate_table1, 43, 1, 'id=43&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=Abc&tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=uid_table1', 'abc/xyz_table1/', '{"id":"43","tx_abc_abc[record]":"uid_table1","tx_abc_abc[action]":"show","tx_abc_abc[controller]":"Abc"}', 0),
(crdate_table1, 43, 1, 'id=43&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=Abc&tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=uid_table1', 'abc/xyz_table1/', '{"id":"43","tx_abc_abc[record]":"uid_table1","tx_abc_abc[action]":"show","tx_abc_abc[controller]":"Abc"}', 0),
(crdate_table1, 43, 1, 'id=43&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=Abc&tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=uid_table1', 'abc/xyz_table1/', '{"id":"43","tx_abc_abc[record]":"uid_table1","tx_abc_abc[action]":"show","tx_abc_abc[controller]":"Abc"}', 0),
(crdate_table1, 43, 1, 'id=43&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=Abc&tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=uid_table1', 'abc/xyz_table1/', '{"id":"43","tx_abc_abc[record]":"uid_table1","tx_abc_abc[action]":"show","tx_abc_abc[controller]":"Abc"}', 0),
(crdate_table1, 43, 1, 'id=43&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=Abc&tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=uid_table1', 'abc/xyz_table1/', '{"id":"43","tx_abc_abc[record]":"uid_table1","tx_abc_abc[action]":"show","tx_abc_abc[controller]":"Abc"}', 0),
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do:

```
insert into table2 (crdate, page_id, rootpage_id, original_url, speaking_url, request_variables, expire)
    select t1.crdate_table1, 43, 1, 
           replace('id=43&tx_abc_abc%5Baction%5D=show&tx_abc_abc%5Bcontroller%5D=Abc&tx_abc_abc%5Brecord%5D=uid_table1', 'uid_table1', t1.uid),
           replace('abc/xyz_table1/', 'xyz_table1', t1.xyz),
           replace('{"id":"43","tx_abc_abc[record]":"uid_table1","tx_abc_abc[action]":"show","tx_abc_abc[controller]":"Abc"}', 'uid_table1', t1.uid),
            0
    from table1 t1;
```

Note the use of `replace()` to insert the values from the other table.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from tx_abc_domain_model_abc t1' at line 7